# Let $R$ be a ring such that $a+b = a \cdot b, \; \forall \, a, b \in R$. Show that $R= \{0\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring such that $a+b = a \cdot b, \; \forall \, a, b \in R$. Show that $R= \{0\}$.

I'm really lost. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Clearly, $0=1$, since $1+0=1$, and $1\cdot0=0$. When $1=0$, the ring is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @DonThousand But I guess the ring doesn't necessarily have to possess a $1$ right? However though I do get your idea

Comment: That depends on your definition of ring -- some people require rings to possess a $1$, some don't. But both of the answers already written take this into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b=0$.  Then we get $a+0=a\cdot0\implies a=0$.  Since $a$ was arbitrary, $\mathcal R=\{0\}$

Comment: I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if you could do this:

Assume it's not identically $0$ then there must exists an element such that it is not the zero element, say $a$ then observe $0\times a=0+a=a$...

Comment: Yea, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!